# Using the pelican i18n subsites plugin with a static home page

Tags: python, internationalization, jinja2, pelican

I have a static homepage, but I'm also using the i18n subsites plugin. So for the homepage I have, in pelicanconf.py:

```
INDEX_SAVE_AS = 'blog/index.html'
INDEX_URL = 'blog'
```

and for the English version:

```
I18N_SUBSITES = {
    'en': {
        'OUTPUT_PATH': 'output/en/',
        'INDEX_SAVE_AS': 'blog/index.html',
        'INDEX_URL': 'blog',
    }
}
```

(truncated unnecessary bits)

The problem lies with the translation link for the homepage. The translations macro has:

```
{% for translation in article.translations %}
    <a href="{{ SITEURL }}/{{ translation.url }}">{{ translation.lang | lookup_lang_name }}</a>
```

So for the English-language homepage I could either set the url and output filename as:

```
    <meta name="save_as" content="en/index.html">
    <meta name="url" content="en/">
```

Which makes the translation link go to site.com/en/en/ (and works), or set them as:

```
    <meta name="save_as" content="index.html">
    <meta name="url" content="/">
```

Which conflicts with the standard-language homepage.

Another, related problem is that the index page (blog page) has no translation link to the English or back to the standard-language version whatsoever.

What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem with the following translations macro:

```
{% macro translations_for(article) %}

    {% if extra_siteurls %}
        {% for lang, url in extra_siteurls.items() %}
            {% if article %}
            <a href="{{ url }}/{{article.permalink}}">{{ lang | lookup_lang_name }}</a>
            {% else %}
            <a href="{{ url }}">{{ lang | lookup_lang_name }}</a>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}

{% endmacro %}
```

And by adding a permalink option the each article and page I can also translate the URL for said article or page (otherwise you could just use slug in the above macro).

Last but not least I also removed the url and save_as data from both homepages.

To fix the blog page, I added this to the index.html template:

```
{% block translation_links %}
    {% if lang == 'nl' %}
    <a href="/en/blog/">English</a>
    {% else %}
    <a href="/blog/">Nederlands</a>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the second part of your question, have a look at [creating language buttons](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican-plugins/blob/master/i18n_subsites/implementing_language_buttons.rst)

Comment: Thanks! That was already actually in an {% else %} statement in my translations macro as a backup, though!